# WSO API Manager - 102510 Error in sender when disabling request chunking

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm currently trying to solve an issue very similar to this one:

https://www.wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-415

I'm trying to disable WSO2 request chunking

I added this property to an outgoing sequence:

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" />
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

Now I'm getting a `500 Error` from WSO2:

```
{"fault":{"code":"102510","type":"Status report",
 "message":"Runtime Error","description":"Error in Sender"}}
```

Comment: what's the apim version you are using?

Comment: @RajeevSampath this fails both in 1.7 and 1.8

Comment: Have you tried with 1.9.1?  A similar issue was there with a previous esb version, so apim 1.7/1.8 may also have it.

Comment: @RajeevSampath thanks for the advice,  will try this. Sadly,  upgrading the version in the company will be a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the version to [`1.9.1`](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/) and everything works as expected. It appears to have been a bug in previous versions of the `ESB`